# jQuery Mobile - Relative links - base tag bug

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, radix

On my application i use the base tag `<base href="http://localhost/app/" />`, and the links uses relative path, like these: `<a href="news/page-1">some link</a>`.

The first page load like a charm, but the next requests tries to load wrong URLs, tested by firebug.

Example:

Base: `http://localhost/app/`

- link 1: news
- link 2: about

on the first request, on link 1, obtain the correct url, `http://localhost/app/news`.

but on the next request, if i click on the link 2, jquery mobile tries to load the following url: `http://localhost/app/news/about`

how to deal with this problem?

use absolute urls is not an option.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug.

And here may be a fix for it.

> [Github - Fix for issue 613](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/02c9264f0da032d67b2cad7625f6f374918d449d) - Jquery Mobile ignores original 'base'
>   tag

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the relative links using jQuery itself, putting this script at the bottom of every page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
 var base = $( 'base' ).attr( 'href' );
 if( base ) {
  // Fix a tags with relative href
  $( 'a[href]' ).filter( function() {
   return ! /^(\w+:|\/)/.test($(this).attr('href'));
  }).each( function() {
   $(this).attr( 'href' , base + $(this).attr( 'href' ) );
  });
 }
//--></script>
```

It basically does the following:

- Test if there is a base tag, in which case:
- Select every 'a' tag having an attribute 'href'
- Filter out tags whose href is an absolute URL (starting with a 'scheme:' or '/')
- Prepend the base tag to the href, making it absolute

It worked out pretty well for me.

Note that it only works with base hrefs ending with a forward slash (such as `'http://localhost/app/'`). Otherwise extra trimming will need to be performed on the base variable.

I'm still trying to figure out how to do the same with images' sources. Trying the same technique fails, as it seems the `img`'s `src` URLs get wrongly converted to absolute before I can fix them using jQuery. If anyones finds a trick, let me know. Meanwhile, I'll be using absolute URLs for images...